# CSS element is not in row

Tags: html, css

```css
.slide{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 7px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color: #2874f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="slide"><</a>
<a class="slide">></a>
```

Please help me How can I add both buttons in the same row with the center align? Right now button 1 is on top and button 2 is in the footer. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: use `display:inline-block` and set `text-align:center` in parent class

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use **flexbox**, it's a very good tool to align items and make responsive web pages. You can find guides [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), that are very clear and will give you the good practices.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.slide{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 7px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #2874f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="slide"><</a>
    <a class="slide">></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.arrow {
  text-align: center;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #2874f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <a class="slide"><</a>
  <a class="slide">></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in class Slide:

```
display: inline-block;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 0px 0px;
```

The elements are not in a row as they are block elements. For your requirement they'll have to be converted to inline-block types.

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexboxes:

```css
section#slider_buttons {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

section.button {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #2874f0;
    color: white;
}

section.button a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto; /* Important */
}
```

```html
<section id="slider_buttons">
    <section class="button">
        <a>&lt;</a>
    </section>
    <section class="button">
        <a>&gt;</a>
    </section>
<section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1) Add BootStrap or a similar framework and wrap the two links in a div with a row class.

2) Change your CSS display setting to inline-block

```
.slide{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 7px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color: #2874f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex is the best tool to achieve this. Despite their are solutions with display block. Flex just allows you to controle it in more detail:

```css
.slide-buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Clarity marker, removed when you understand the example */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.slide-buttons > a {
  display: inherit;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  margin-right: 5px;

  cursor: pointer;
  
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #2874f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
.slide-buttons > a:last-child { 
  margin-right: 0;
}
#bt-slide-left:after {
  content: '\276E'; /* \003C */
}
#bt-slide-right:after {
  content: '\276F'; /* \003E */
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-buttons">
  <a id="bt-slide-left"></a>
  <a id="bt-slide-right"></a>
</div>

<br>

<!-- or -->
<div class="slide-buttons">
  <a>&#60;</a>
  <a>&#62;</a>
</div>
```